# best way to use node-worker-threads-pool with for loop

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads

I'm using node-worker-threads-pool to process a daily function on all the documents from one collection, for that I'm using a for loop to send the id of each document to the pool, I'm trying to get the time that it takes to process the whole process but it consoles before the execution of all the id's, so I have two questions, is better to run the for loop inside of the worker file so the pool.exec() function is just called once?, and how can I log the time with the actual code?. Here is my code:

```
Client.find({}, {_id: 1}).then(clients => {
        console.time('clientDayChange');

        const pool = new StaticPool({
            size: 8,
            task: "./worker.js"
        });
        
        for(let client of clients){
            let id = JSON.stringify(client._id);
            pool.exec(id);
        }
        
        console.timeEnd('clientDayChange');
   })
```

Comment: Hopefully you can use `await` inside an `async` function as `then` is always such a pain.

Comment: Presumably `pool.exec` returns a promise, so you should do something with it rather than discard the result.  Also, "Is it better to..." / "what's the best way to..." is a bad way to phrase a question, because "better" and "best" are not always as objective as you think they are without clear criteria upon which to judge it.  Otherwise, such questions are sometimes vague and elicit opinions.  You can just try both approaches and tell us which is better for you.  "How can I..." is a much better phrasing for stack overflow questions as it forces you to articulate your objectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your existing code, `console.timeEnd('clientDayChange');` is executed before all the worker tasks are completed because `pool.exec(id)` is asynchronous. You have two options to get the accurate time it takes to process all the tasks:

#### Option 1: Run the loop inside the worker

If running the for-loop inside the worker file is possible and does not create any issue with the logic of your application, then it is a good approach. By doing so, you only invoke `pool.exec()` once, which can be efficient. Here's how you can do it:

In your `worker.js`:

```js
// Existing worker logic
module.exports = async function worker(ids) {
  for(let id of ids) {
    // Process each id
  }
}
```

In your main file:

```js
Client.find({}, {_id: 1}).then(clients => {
  console.time('clientDayChange');

  const pool = new StaticPool({
    size: 8,
    task: "./worker.js"
  });

  let ids = clients.map(client => client._id);
  pool.exec(ids).then(() => {
    console.timeEnd('clientDayChange');
  });
});
```

#### Option 2: Use `Promise.all` to wait for all tasks to finish

If you want to keep the for-loop in the main file, you can use `Promise.all` to wait for all the tasks to complete before you stop the timer. Here's how:

```js
Client.find({}, {_id: 1}).then(async clients => {
  console.time('clientDayChange');

  const pool = new StaticPool({
    size: 8,
    task: "./worker.js"
  });

  const promises = [];
  for(let client of clients){
    let id = JSON.stringify(client._id);
    promises.push(pool.exec(id));
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);
  
  console.timeEnd('clientDayChange');
});
```